# react onChange bind value to array in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react js and am trying to build a simple magic square game. I am able to populate initial values. I am stuck at figuring out a way to get user input to reflect in parent component. i.e. set new value entered in the empty Square to the squares[i] in handleChange(i) method of Board class.

```
class Square extends React.Component {

  render()
  {
    return (
      <input type="text" className="square" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
      </input>
    );
  }
}

/* Defines the Main Game Board */
class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    /*Array to store Random numbers*/
    const randArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
      var numberIsInArray = false;
      var rand = generateRandomNumb(1, 9);
      for(var j = 0; j < randArray.length; j++){
          if(rand === randArray[j]) {
              numberIsInArray = true;
              i--;
          }
      }
      if(!numberIsInArray){
         randArray.push(rand);
      }
    }

    /*function to generate Random Numbers*/
    function generateRandomNumb(min, max) 
    {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    }

    function check(grid_val, arr)
    {
      if (arr[0] === grid_val || arr[1] === grid_val || arr[2] === grid_val)
        return grid_val;
    }

    this.state = {
      squares: Array(
         (4,check(4,randArray))
        ,(9,check(9,randArray))
        ,(2,check(2,randArray))
        ,(3,check(3,randArray))
        ,(5,check(5,randArray))
        ,(7,check(7,randArray))
        ,(8,check(8,randArray))
        ,(1,check(1,randArray))
        ,(6,check(6,randArray))
        )
    };
  }

  handleChange(i) {
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = '';
    //this.setState({squares: squares});
  }

  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.state.squares[i]}
        onChange={this.handleChange(i)}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {

    const status = this.state.squares;    

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Sudoku React</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => window.location.reload()}>Start New Game</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Board;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues here.

**Issue 1**

When you create a `<Square />` component you are passing props named `value` and `onChange`. However in the Square component, you are attempting to use `this.handleChange` as the `onChange` handler.

`this.handleChange` does exist as a property of the `Square`. Instead you should be using the `this.props.onChange` that has been passed to it by the `Board` parent.

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  // handleChange () {
  // this is the none existant function referred to in the render function 
  // Instead: use this.props.onChange passed by the parent <Board /> 
  // }

  render()
  {
    return (
      <input type="text" className="square" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
      </input>
    );
  }
}
```

This will still not work though, due to...

**Issue 2**

The input's `onChange` method is expected to be a function.

With issue #1 fixed, Square's `this.props.onChange` would be `undefined`. 
This is because `handleChange` is being invoked (called) as we pass it as prop. As `handleChange` has no return value, we pass `undefined`.

```
renderSquare(i) {
  return (
    <Square
      value={this.state.squares[i]}
      onChange={this.handleChange(i)} // handleChange is being invoked! Note ()
    />
  );
}
```

The minimum edit need to fix this, is to have `handleChange` return a function, which accepts an event, that we use to update our state.

```
handleChange (i) {
  // Return ES6 bound function to maintain `this`
  return (e) => {
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = e.target.value; // The value of the input
    this.setState({squares: squares});
  };
}
```

P.s. Some additional general comments;
`renderSquare` should be bound to `this` in the constructor like `handleChange` is

```
this.renderSquare = this.renderSquare.bind(this);
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

I would also move `generateRandomNumb` and `check` out of the constructor of `<Board />`, and place them at the very top your example code, outside of any `class`.

Also move the `randArray` generation into a function too, and also move to the top.

```
function generateRandArray () {
  var randArray = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
  {
    var numberIsInArray = false;
    var rand = generateRandomNumb(1, 9);
    for(var j = 0; j < randArray.length; j++){
      if(rand === randArray[j]) {
        numberIsInArray = true;
        i--;
      }
    }
    if(!numberIsInArray){
      randArray.push(rand);
    }
  }
  return randArray;
}
```

And in the constructor of `<Board />`

```
const randArray = generateRandArray();
```

Comment: I think this might solve my issue, but I'm not sure.  Could you provide an example with all the suggested code changes in one code block?